# Authentication via an LDAP server

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans

i have just created a web app using JSF etc but i now need to authenticate all users via the LDAP sever

i have created a php code to do this but my supervisor told me to do it another way in glass fish or something as it is better, is there any tutorials etc ?

I can post my code for the php if that helps as i know this code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know glassfish. However most java web servers or servlet containers allow to configure JAAS. You configure the security in the `web.xml` and let your container take care of the rest(well after configuration of course).

I just at a quick look at the following [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security) and it explains the basic. If you check the glassfish documentation it will probably tell you how you can configure your ldap. Hitting google with `JAAS glassfish` and `glassfish ldap` will probably bring up the desired results.